# Menu item seperators not visible under GNOME environment (while using "GTK" LAF)

Tags: java, swing, gtk, gnome

I have a Java desktop application (document editor) for where I recently added a menubar, with menus which in turn have menu items. The problem is that - in my GNOME desktop environment (Ubuntu) the menu item separators are not visible at all. They are visible if I switch the application L&F to default Java (metal) LaF or to switch the desktop environment KDE environment on Ubuntu, but the menu item separators are never visible under GNOME environment. Also I am setting the application L&F to "GTK". If I force the L&F to "motif" the file separators can be clearly seen.

Has anyone else ever faced this kind of a problem before on Ubuntu GNOME environment? I am attaching the code below - which is straight forward and don't think there is any problem here.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {
    static JFrame frame = null;
    static JMenuBar menubar = null;
    static JMenu filemenu = null;
    public static void main (String[] args) throws InterruptedException, 
        InvocationTargetException {
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable () {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI ();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI () {
        /* Set LAF to GTK LAF */
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /* Create frame */
        frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setLocation(50, 50);
        frame.setSize(400, 600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        /* Add menu bar */
        addMenuBar ();
    }

    private static void addMenuBar () {
        /* Create menu bar and then file menu*/
        menubar = new JMenuBar ();
        filemenu = new JMenu ("File");

        /* Add three menu items to the file menu */
        JMenuItem newItem = new JMenuItem ("New       ");
        JMenuItem openItem = new JMenuItem ("Open      ");
        JMenuItem exitItem = new JMenuItem ("Exit     ");

        /* Add the menu items to the file menu. Also separate the last item
         * from the first two using a menu item separator */
        filemenu.add(newItem);
        filemenu.add(openItem);

        filemenu.addSeparator();
        filemenu.add(exitItem);

        /* Add the file menu to the menu bar */
        menubar.add(filemenu);

        /* Add menu bar to frame */
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }
}
```

So the question is - do I need to add some more customization when using "GTK" L&F in GNOME environment so that the menu item separators are visible again?

[Edit: the post has now been edited to reflect an sscce. If you want to see the effect of Java LAF then please comment out the lines inside the createAndShowGUI () where the LAF is hardcoded to GTK LAF. The problem goes away with Java LAF but remains when using GTK LAF]

Comment: Please provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Updated code to contain a small sscce.

Comment: I see get the same result; I wonder if it's an intentional UI decision or if GTK+ is intended for use in [this context](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javagnometutorial/menus/).

Comment: Maybe gnome thinks of separators as iconsBy default, gnome does not show menu icons and you should turn it on.
use dconf-editor (install dconf-tools if you don't have it)
go under org.gnome.desktop.interface and turn on menus-have-iconsBy default, gnome does not show menu icons and you should turn it on.
use dconf-editor (install dconf-tools if you don't have it)
go under org.gnome.desktop.interface and turn on menus-have-icons